# Plotting Problems: Missing Legend Frame and Label, LabelStyle ignored

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I often struggle with getting MMA to plot as I plan.  Here's two examples

1. I try to first define a set of desired default plotting values and then can't get them to work. Below I want the text of `PlotLabel` to be in `Black`, but it's in `Gray` (yet the rest of the labels are `Black` as desired).
2. I am adding a legend and yet I can't get it framed nor labeled.

What am I doing wrong?

```
(*Setting global options for plotting*)
fontsize = 14;
thickness = Thickness[0.005];

$PlotStyle = {{thickness, Black}, {thickness, Dashed}, {thickness, 
   Dotted}}

$TextStyle = {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> fontsize, 
  FontWeight -> "Bold", FontColor -> Black}

SetOptions[{Plot, LogPlot, Histogram, ListPlot, ListLogPlot, 
   LogLogPlot, ListLogLogPlot, ListLogLinearPlot, BarChart}, 
  Background -> White, PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0.025, 0.95}}, 
  ImageSize -> 8*72, FrameStyle -> thickness, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> $TextStyle,
  LabelStyle -> $TextStyle];

SetOptions[{Plot, LogPlot,  ListPlot, ListLogPlot, LogLogPlot, 
   ListLogLogPlot, ListLogLinearPlot}, PlotStyle -> $PlotStyle];
```

(*Function to be used *)

```
expectedRF[k_] := .50*(1 - PDF[PoissonDistribution[k], 0])

(*Generate Plot*)

kmax = 4;
dashedHLine = {Dotted, Line[{{0, 0.5}, {kmax, 0.5}}]};

Plot[{expectedRF[k], 1 - expectedRF[k]}, {k, 0, kmax}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Recombinant", "Parental"},
 FrameLabel -> {"Expected # of Crossovers: \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(k\), \
\(_\)]\)", "Frequency"},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 PlotLabel -> 
  Column[{"Parental & Recombinant Genotype Frequency",  
    "vs. Expected # of Crossovers"}, Center],
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Recombinant", "Parental"}, 
   LegendLabel -> "Genotype", 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#] &)],
 PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 Epilog -> dashedHLine
 ]
```

Here's what I get
[image: Gray PlotLabel and No LegendLabel]

System Info:"13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"

Comment: Okay, I figured out 2).  I have two `PlotLegends` commands.  FWIW, I would have thought the second one would have overridden the first.